# How to get information from previously "gone" Spinner?

Tags: android

The question is about android Spinners working when "Gone" and then "Visible" again.

I've got a form where spinner is hidden ("Gone") by default. If user checks checkbox, it appears and allows to choose something. The problem is when I do submit info from the form without touching the checkbox (i.e. default value is chosen from spinner), App crashes with nullpointer exception - despite I`m setting spinner as visible.

If I click checkbox (even twice, to make Spinner gone again) - everything works fine. If I use invisible instead of gone, everything works fine even without touching the button.

How to make it work with spinner "Gone" by default?

Here`s code on how checkbox behaves (onclick checkbox):

```
        case R.id.checkboxUseDefaultURLList:
        {
            final CheckBox checkBoxDefaultList = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxUseDefaultURLList);
            final TextView textViewEmpty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBlank);
            final Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerURLList);
            if (checkBoxDefaultList.isChecked()) {
                textViewEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE); // GONE
                textViewEmpty.invalidate();
                s2.setVisibility(View.GONE); // GONE
                s2.invalidate();
                }           
            if (!checkBoxDefaultList.isChecked()) {
                textViewEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // VISIBLE
                textViewEmpty.invalidate();
                s2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // VISIBLE
                s2.invalidate();
                }
            break;
        }
```

here`s how I get values from Spinner (in onclick of "submit" button):

```
                    Spinner spinURLList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerURLList);
                spinURLList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinURLList.invalidate();
                spinURLList.setSelection(0);
                TextView chosenURLTV = (TextView) spinURLList.getSelectedView();
                String urlListSelected = chosenURLTV.getText().toString();
```

Any ideas why it crashes if I don`t click on checkbox before submitting?

Comment: Which line throws the null pointer?

Comment: can you post logcat output? Only the crash report part.

Comment: 2 Tim: last one (  String urlListSelected = chosenURLTV.getText().toString(); )

Comment: @Nick, you can throw the '@' symbol before the user's name you want to speak directly to.

Comment: 2 user7777777777:

08-14 19:14:58.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 19:14:58.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4141): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 19:14:58.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at org.my.client.android.TestDetails.onClick(TestDetails.java:125)
08-14 19:14:58.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
...

Comment: @Phil , submit code is second part - I don`t think it`s relevant because it`s the last line that crashes (see my answer to Tim)

Comment: @Nick. Suggestion. You should have posted the crash report in the question by editing it.

Comment: @user7777777777 thanks for your suggestion but the problem is solved - thanks to Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a problem of assigning the `TextView` the text in the spinner. Try:

```
String urlListSelected = spinURLList.getSelectedItem().toString();
```